# How do I delete a single character in a string and use recursion in a string

Tags: c++, string, recursion

I'm not sure how I would delete a single character in my string because when  I use str.erase(x,y) from my understanding it would delete everything from "x" to "y". However, I just want to delete one character at "x".

I also need to use recursion for this problem.

I need to delete a random character from a string and output it and keep doing so until the string is empty.

```
string ObliterateString(string arg)
{

  int length = arg.length();
  int random = 0;

  while(length > 0)
  {
    if(length <= 1)
    {
      return ObliterateString("");
    }
    else{
      random = rand() % length; //Get a random number that is between 0 and the length of the string
      arg.erase(random,random);
      cout << arg << endl;
    }
    length--;
  }

  return arg;
}
```

Comment: To answer my first question, arg.erase(random,1) does work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursive routine should handle without the while-loop: Try this:

```
string ObliterateString(string arg)
{
    int length = arg.length();

    if (length <= 1)
    {
        return "";
    }
    else
    {
        int random;
        random = rand() % length;
        arg.erase(random, 1);
        cout << arg << endl;
        arg = ObliterateString(arg);
    }

    return arg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void ObliterateString(string arg) {
  if (arg.empty())
    return;
  random = rand() % arg.length(); //Get a random number that is between 0 and the length of the string
  arg.erase(random, 1);
  cout << arg << endl;
  ObliterateString(arg);
}
```